# How to show navigation links in article

Tags: joomla

Please assist for this function. I'm using joomla.
I want to show navigation link in my article, like this:-

Home > maiActivities2019 > ARCHIDEX > Exhibition

Comment: Please post your Joomla questions at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange as well.  Neil will be happy to help you there too.

Answer (score 2):

The basic steps are as follows:

In Extensions -> Modules, click on the "New" button and select "Breadcrumbs".

Enter a Title e.g. "Breadcrumbs", set Show Title = "Hide", choose a suitable module position e.g. "breadcrumbs" or "content-top-a" or similar (depends on your template), then click on "Save and Close".